# Trying to send a String (username) from the client to the server in React and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send the username of a logged-in person from the Client to the Server as a string. I am already sending a file (image) but I also want to send a string as well.
Essentially what I wanna do is in the **Server Side File** to replace the `'public_id'` with `username` from Client-side.

As you can see below I am already sending the image (file) that I want to the server. I have used `console.log(loggedInUser?.username);` to show the string that I want to be sent.

Hope this was enough to explain what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance.

**Client Side file**

```js
  console.log(loggedInUser?.username);

  const uploadImage = async (base64EncodedImage: string) => {
    try {
      await fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage }),
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

**Server side file**

```js
app.post("/api/upload", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fileStr = req.body.data;
    const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileStr, {
      upload_preset: "geekyimages",
      public_id: "public_id",
      invalidate: true,
    });
    console.log(uploadedResponse);
    res.json({ msg: "Uploaded" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ err: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send both inside a single JSON-Object:

```
// client side

await fetch('/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
        data: base64EncodedImage, 
        username: loggedInUser?.username 
    }),
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
});


// server side

const username = req.body.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

From here

```
await fetch('/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage }),
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
  });
```

Just add a username in the body like

```
await fetch('/api/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage, username: username: loggedInUser?.username || "SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE" }), // The default value is in case you an have a null or undefined username
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
```

You can also prevent this behavior adding this check

```
if (loggedInUser?.username) ... // The code without default value
else { // A message }
```